# Segmentation fault while using pthread_setname_np

Tags: python, pthreads, python-multithreading

I'm trying to patch thread names using the thread name libpthread.pthread_setname_np function in python like so

'''

```
libpthread = ctypes.CDLL("libpthread.so")
if not libpthread:
    # no pthread library, not patching
    return

if not hasattr(libpthread, "pthread_setname_np"):
    # pthread library does not have pthread_setname_np function, not patching
    return

pthread_setname_np = libpthread.pthread_setname_np
pthread_setname_np.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_char_p]
pthread_setname_np.restype = ctypes.c_int
orig_start = threading.Thread.start

def start(self):
    """Patched version of threading.Thread.start"""
    orig_start(self)
    try:
        name = self.name
        if name:
            if hasattr(name, "encode"):
                name = name.encode('ascii', 'replace')
            ident = getattr(self, "ident", None)
            if ident is not None:
                pthread_setname_np(ident, name[:15])
    except Exception: # pylint: disable=broad-except
        pass  # Don't care about failure to set name
```

'''

The following is code is proving me with a segmentation fault with the following message.

segfault error 4 in libpthread-2.31.so

Any inputs on what could be causing this issue.

Comment: can you provide full example? with this piece it's not clear how thread is created